# Xcode 8 crash on launch after reinstalling Python

Tags: python, ios, xcode

Xcode is crashing after I installed and reinstalled Python. I'm not sure what to check.

Here are all the errors I've found:

**From Xcode:**

```
Loading a plug-in failed.
The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.
```

**From The Console:**

```
Library Validation failed: Rejecting '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (Team ID: none, platform: no) for process 'Xcode(14584)' (Team ID: none, platform: yes), reason: mapped file has no cdhash (unsigned or signature broken?)
```